# $p , q , r$ are prime $ {p}\times{q}\times{r} = r(p+q+r)$ Given some arbitrary prime $r$ what are the values of $q$ and $p$?

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, prime-numbers

$p , q , r$ are **prime numbers**, where $ {p}\times{q}\times{r} = r(p+q+r)$ and $ {p}\lt{q}\lt{r} $

What are the values of $q$ and $p$ if given some arbitrary prime $r$ ?

Comment: I see you here again. In this site, it is recommended you show some effort. So a link with the previous question, or your attempt should be asked with the question.

Comment: Well, pq =p+q+r so p =(q+r)(q-1) and q=(p+r)(p-1).  No reason to assume there's standard way to solve.

Comment: This case also has been tackled here [http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2118665/p-q-r-are-prime-numbers-where-p-timesq-timesr-19pqr-and]